# JWT Auth0 gives me an error: ClassNotFoundException, but i have imports

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs, token, auth0

I want to make a web service that implements a token to authenticate.

I receive this error:

Advertencia: StandardWrapperValve[jersey-serlvet]: Servlet.service() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.JWTSigner

This is my code:

```
     import com.auth0.jwt.JWTSigner;
     import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
     import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifyException;
     import java.util.HashMap;
     import java.util.Map;

     //....

       ...//
public String crearToken(String username) {
    String token = null;
    final long iat = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000l; // issued at claim 
    final long exp = iat + 60L; // expires claim. In this case the token expires in 60 seconds
    final JWTSigner signer = new JWTSigner(this.key);
    final HashMap<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    claims.put("iss", username);
    claims.put("exp", exp);
    claims.put("iat", iat);
    claims.put("aud",aud);


    token = signer.sign(claims);
    return token;
}

public void validarToken(String token)throws Exception{       

    try {
           JWTVerifier jwtVerifier1 = new JWTVerifier(key);          
    jwtVerifier1.verify(token);}      

     catch(Exception e){             

     }
}
```

And my endpoint:

```
           @POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response authenticateUser(Credentials credentials) {

    String username = credentials.getUsername();
    String password = credentials.getPassword();

    try {

        Authenticate auth= new Authenticate();
        //Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
        auth.authenticateUser(username, password);

        Token tok= new Token();
        // Issue a token for the user
        String token = tok.crearToken(username);

        // Return the token on the response
        return Response.ok(token).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }      
}
```

Someone has an idea why it gives me that error or am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also need to provide the jars at runtime, so you need to bundle them in your jar/war, depending on how you package and deploy your software. That's what the error is complaining about.

Comment: The `import` statements are for the compiler. They have no explicit meaning at runtime. Your error is a runtime exception, basically complaining that you're missing a jar file from the classpath.

Comment: Thx,I was only adding jar, not a library with jar.